# clarify Javascript Callback flow

Tags: javascript, callback, asynccallback

I have a few different code paths with multiple callbacks.

```
this.confirmJWT(
  function() {
    this.confirmVendorCode(
      function() {
        this.downloadFile(FORECAST);
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }.bind(this)
);
```

I'm aware that people call this callback hell (actually just found http://callbackhell.com/ ), but I'm looking for the preferred way to write this browser code.

Comment: If you don't tell us what the code is doing (e.g. by showing the implementations of the used functions), we cannot suggest to change anything without the risk of breaking the functionality.

Comment: Probably a better question for [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Writing it using ES6 would make it shorter, perhaps not as readable though.

```
this.confirmJWT(() => this.confirmVendorCode(() => this.downloadFile(FORECAST)));
```

Comment: The context of `this` is different in arrow functions versus function declarations. Is there any way to know that this won't break functionality?

Comment: @DanMandel, since arrow functions just inherit `this` from their parent, and OP's example is binding parent `this`, they are both using the same `this`

Comment: yeah this does make it look nicer to write the anonymous functions.